# Mercurial - How to get a list of files that are different between two repositories

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have two related Mercurial repositories. Repository A has a lot of changes that are not in repository B. I want to generate a list of file names that are different between repository A and repository B

Here is what I have so far:

A text file named hg_outconfig.txt with the following text:

```
changeset = "{file_mods}\n{file_dels}\n{file_adds}"
file_mod = "{file_mod}\n"
file_add = "{file_add}\n"
file_del = "{file_del}\n"
```

Then I am running the commands:

```
cd PATH_TO_REPO_A
hg -q outgoing URL_TO_REPO_B --style c:\\hg_outconfig.txt | sort
```

This does list all files in repo A that have changed, but it also lists files in repo A that have changes from previous commits that are already in repo B. I want just a list of files that have current differences between repo A and repo B.

Answer (score 0):

`... --template "{files}\n"` will give you far from nice and pretty, but correct output

From my test

```
hg incoming --template="{files}\n" -q
footer.php functions.php header.php readme.txt search.php style.css
comments.php functions.php header.php readme.txt sidebar.php style.css
readme.txt sidebar.php style.css
functions.php readme.txt screenshot.png style.css
```

4 strings are 4 changesets, files in changeset are space-separated

Comment: That will give you all files that are in the changset that is incoming which is usually more than just the files that are diffent since the incoming changeset can have commits that already exists in the other repository.

Comment: A changeset is generated by a commit and there's only one changeset per commit.  `hg incoming` only shows changesets that need to be applied to the repository and so that won't include commits that have already been made to it.  By "commits that already exist" do you mean that you have made the same change to a file in both repositories but committed them into each repository?  If so, I'm not sure that you can do what you want without using an external diff program.

Comment: @Coltech - incoming (nad pull later, apparently) **can (must) NOT** show /and process/) *changesets*, which exist in destinaton repository. Just because they are **already synced**. Incoming (by nature) will show changed *files* more than once each, if they was changed in more than one commit, will show **all files** in bundle (changed only in SRC, in SRC and DST, new in SRC)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out how to do this. In order to list outgoing files and exclude merges you can use the -M argument with the outgoing command. So

```
hg -q outgoing -M remote_repo_url
```

will give you a list of files that are different between the two repositories.